# Nokia QT SDK Thread Concept

Tags: qt, qt4

Can any one tell me please about the Thread in QT.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you question is, but you can have a look at the Qt documentation:

[QThread](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qthread.html)